# How can I obtain the original (Exchange) folder UniqueID in Outlook PlugIn (VSTO)?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, office-interop

After spending few hours trying to get an answer to my question, I decided that is time to ask a question on SO because maybe there is someone who knows from which MAPI property I can get this information.

But let's get it from the beginning - I'm writing a VSTO plugin for Outlook 2013 / 2016 in C#; somewhere in this plugin, I'm getting the list of folders in my current store and everything works fine - for each folder I have an entry id and other properties; my big question is - how can I get for a folder or for an item (Email) the original ID that that item has on the server (for people who uses EWS is the FolderId.UniqueId for folders) - most probably this information resides somewhere in a MAPI hidden property that can be accessed using PropertyAccessor.

From what I've read so far, there are few thousands MAPI properties available for Outlook items / folders but I have no idea which are the Exchange related ones.

Thank you very much for any clue.

Answer (score 0):

You mean use an unique id for each item that is from Exchange Server, not from local outlook application. You may consider to use

EntryID: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866458.aspx

I tried to leave comment, but with company merging we moved to a new domain, I have a new email address, and a new ID here, reputation starting from zero again!

Comment: This is  the entry id which is created by outlook when the object is added to the store and this is not what I'm looking for.  What I need is the unique is which is coming from the exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

After getting some clues over some other posts, it seems that what I was looking for is called "Convert VSTO EntryID to EWS ID" (at least that is what I googled for :-).

Long story short, I found the solution on multiple website but the correct one can be found here:

https://bernhardelbl.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/converting-entryid-to-ewsid-using-exchange-web-services-ews/

In few words, it seems that this operation is somehow different then what I thought it should be - this EWS ID that I was looking for doesn't reside in the outlook items; in order to obtain it, you have to call EWS and you will get the response from the server:

```
string ConvertHexEntryIdToEwsId(ExchangeService esb, string sID, string strSMTPAdd)
{
AlternateId objAltID = new AlternateId();
objAltID.Format = IdFormat.HexEntryId;
objAltID.Mailbox = strSMTPAdd;
objAltID.UniqueId = sID;

AlternateIdBase objAltIDBase = esb.ConvertId(objAltID, IdFormat.EwsId);
AlternateId objAltIDResp = (AlternateId)objAltIDBase;
return objAltIDResp.UniqueId;
}
```